# Panda on pro-webmasters

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

Is it the appropriate site to ask a question about Panda and share insights about that the effects of that new algorithm on SEO ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the perfect place to ask it as [SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) is our most popular topic.